# Javascript make subtraction in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a POS project, and I need to do a subtraction in real-time for the tip after I have manually add the amount of money the client gave. I am not sure what is going wrong with my code, so a little help please.

```
<div class="sidebar-category">
    <div class="category-content" style="padding: 8px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="client_paid" type="text" placeholder="Paguar" class="form-control" >
                <br>
                <input  id="change" type="text" placeholder="Resto" class="form-control change">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h6 class="text-semibold text-right no-margin-top">Totali: <span id = "all-products-subtotal"> {{Session::get('all_products_subtotal') ? number_format(Session::get('all_products_subtotal'),2,",","."):'0'}} </span> </h6>
                <ul class="list list-unstyled text-right">
                Status: &nbsp;
                <a href="#" class="label bg-success-400 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Online</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this the script:

```
<script>
    $("#client_paid").keyup(function(){
        var client_paid = this.val();
        var total ={{Session::get('all_products_subtotal') ? number_format(Session::get('all_products_subtotal'),2,",","."):'0'}};

        if(client_paid >= total){
            var change = client_paid - total;
            $("#change").val(change);
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Here is a illustrating picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nACcp.png)

Comment: ok and whats not working.

Comment: it is not working mate, it doesnt get the tip, and also the total in console is like 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number'

Comment: I don't think it's  the downvoting system, it should work.

Comment: please explain clearly what you want to accomplish with no ambiguity and also what you wish the end result to be.

Comment: what is this `{Session::get`? looks like you use some library here, so just tag it for others in that field to jump in here.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw i need that from 'Paid' input to be real time subtracted total and to show the result in 'Tip' field.

Comment: @KingKing with Session::get I get the total couse products are added "to cart" by ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your function is firing up properly, are you using `$(document).ready`? Also you might want to try replacing `this.val()` with `$(this).val()`